# Purpose of repeating a 16-byte key for Salsa20

Tags: keys, salsa20

The core of the Salsa20 family of stream ciphers is a hash function that takes a 64-byte block, using it to generate a pseudorandom 64-byte output. The 64 bytes contain space for

- a 32-byte key
- a 16-byte constant
- an 8-byte counter
- an 8-byte nonce

These ciphers are intended to be used with 32 byte keys, but they can also be used with smaller keys. Using a 16 byte key involves changing the constant so there are no equivalent keys between the different sizes, and repeating the 16-byte key so it fits into 32 bytes (i.e. the input is $k \mathbin\| k$ for a 16-byte $k$ and just $k$ for a 32-byte $k$).

Why is this done? Why is the key not simply zero-padded? If cryptanalysis (but not exhaustive search) of the keystream can be made easier when a key without uniform distribution is used, the scheme is broken.

From section 4.1 of [The Salsa20 family of stream ciphers](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle/salsafamily-20071225.pdf):

> The diagonal constants are the same for every block, every nonce, and every 32-byte key. As an extra (non-recommended) option, Salsa20 can use a 16-byte key, repeated to form a 32-byte key; in this case the diagonal constants change to 0x61707865, 0x3120646e, 0x79622d36, 0x6b206574.

Comment: Does the downvoter care to explain the issue with my question? Anonymous downvotes help no one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we fix the second half of the key to all zeros we have at least 2 potential issues:

1. The zero-bits offer no additional diffusion effect, whereas repeating the key increases the diffusion effect.
2. Normally the adversary would know $1/2$ of the input and control $1/4$, but with $16$ more static known bytes, the adversary now knows $3/4$ of the input. This might give the adversary enough control to mount more attacks that may have not yet been analyzed; though likely only with a reduced round chacha.

Without doing the expensive analysis, I can only conjecture that the static zero bytes would only weaken chacha. I do not know by how much, but I do doubt it'll be enough to break the full 20-round chacha.

Comment: I suspected #1 at least, but considered that the cipher would have to be pretty broken if that were the case (if I recall, DJB conjectured that there are no classes of weak keys).

Comment: With fewer rounds it may be relevant. At the full 20-rounds, shouldn't make any difference. So yes, it would have to be pretty broken. But why risk it when you've got the bits and it is **really** cheap?

Comment: Ah, so it's purely done because it can't hurt and because it might help slightly in a worst-case scenario?

Comment: As far as I know and can tell, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You say,

> If cryptanalysis (but not exhaustive search) of the keystream can be made easier when a key without uniform distribution is used, the scheme is broken.

But this is outside the [security conjecture of Salsa20](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle/security.pdf):

> If the Salsa20 key $k$ is uniform random…the random function $n \mapsto \operatorname{Salsa20}_k(n)$ from $\{0, 1, \dots, 255\}^{16}$ to $\{0, 1, \dots, 255\}^{64}$ is conjectured to be indistinguishable from uniform random.

In particular, related-key attacks are explicitly excluded from consideration:

> The standard solutions to all the standard cryptographic problems—encryption, authentication, etc.—are protocols that do not allow related-key attacks on the underlying primitives.  I see no evidence that we can save time by violating this condition.  The reader might guess that Salsa20 is highly resistant to related-key attacks; but I simply don't care.

That said, [the Salsa20 family](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#salsafamily) technically supports 80-bit keys too—which are *zero-padded up to 128 bits* and then repeated as if with 128-bit keys, but with, again, a different constant.  (I've never heard of anyone using this; 80-bit keys are ridiculous!)

Neither of these decisions—repeating *vs.* zero-padding the key—appears to be discussed in any of the design documents.  It seems unlikely to me that the choice of one or the other makes much of a difference to security, but you'll have to talk to a real cryptanalyst, not a pseudonymous carrion bird who plays one on the internet.

Comment: The 80-bit keys are zero-padded only because it is not a multiple of 256-bit keys. I guess I should read up more to see if anyone has done any analysis on whether or not related key attacks are applicable to Salsa20/ChaCha, considering DJB "simply doesn't care" (that statement took me by surprise when I first read the paper).

Comment: @forest Most cryptographers don't care about related-key attacks.  Only exotic or badly designed protocols rely on resistance to them.

Comment: But clearly a partially attacker-controlled key was taken into account for the cipher's threat model, as σ exists specifically to reduce that risk.